# Camel useOriginalMessage not working

Tags: java, apache-camel

The first route to produce the input body.

```
    from("timer://bar?fixedRate=true&period=10000s")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("some message");
                }
            }).to("direct:dummydata");
```

The second route to throw the exception and catch it by `onException`.

```
onException(RuntimeException.class)
            .useOriginalMessage()
            .handled(true)
            .log("after catching: ${body}");

    from("direct:dummydata")
            .log("before exception: ${body}.")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    throw new RuntimeException("some exception");
                }
            });
```

**Expected:** 
before exception: some message.
after catching: some message.

**Reality:**

```
2016-04-18 18:08:02.342  INFO 5659 --- [0 - timer://bar] route2                                   : 
before exception: some message.
2016-04-18 18:08:02.345  INFO 5659 --- [0 - timer://bar] route2                                   : 
after catching: 
2016-04-18 18:08:02.349 ERROR 5659 --- [0 - timer://bar] 
o.a.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  : Failed delivery for 
(MessageId: ID-sdcit001mac-49629-1460974079807-0-1 on ExchangeId: 
ID-sdcit001mac-49629-1460974079807-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 
1 caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: some exception. Processed by failure processor: 
FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[Log(route2)[after catching: ${body}]]]
```

Why the `useOriginalMessage()` is not working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the use of "direct:". If you change that to "direct:vm" and you should see the result you want.

Perhaps the underlying reason has to do with "direct:" being treated almost as if it is a direct call from the first route, thus implying an empty starting body (from the timer).

Answer (score 3):

As, I see You have 3 Routes

1. Starting of route. **Timer**
2. Route including processor. **direct:dummydata**
3. Exception Route. **RuntimeException.class**

It is very simple. I have modified your question.

1. In beginning your body message is null.

And, I see you are using  `.useOriginalMessage()` which means use the exact same message which was present in starting of route which is **NULL** in this case. When you will comment or remove `.useOriginalMessage()` then it will show you your body **some message.**

Update the Exception as below then it will show your message.

```
onException(RuntimeException.class)
            //.useOriginalMessage()
            .handled(true)
            .log("after catching: ${body}");
```